# Sitecore Installation failed, removed value from InvalidItemNameChars and disabled ItemNameValidation but still getting error

Tags: installation, sitecore, sitecore8, invalid-characters

I'm trying to install the Sitecore Experience Extractor package in Sitecore 8.0. I keep getting the error "An item name cannot contain any of the following characters: /:?"<>|[]- (controlled by the setting InvalidItemNameChars)". I updated my web config to remove the invalid characters:

```
  <setting name="InvalidItemNameChars" value="" />
  <!--  ITEM NAME VALIDATION
        Regular expression for validating item names
  -->
  <setting name="ItemNameValidation" value="" />
  <!--  ITEM NOT FOUND HANDLER
        Url of page handling 'Item not found' errors
  -->
```

I also added a patch based on this post:https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/5503/sitcore-wffm-installation-error-an-item-name-cannot-contain-any-of-the-follow

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <settings>
      <setting name="ItemNameValidation">
        <patch:attribute name="value"></patch:attribute>
      </setting>
    </settings>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: I don't know the answer to the question, but the patch looks incorrect. It looks like you are patching an attribute on the setting named 'false' with a blank value. The name should be "value".

What does your ShowConfig.aspx show after Sitecore is spun up? That will tell you what the final value is after it has read all configs and patches.

Comment: I checked the showconfig and it turns out that there was another patch that was setting InvalidItemNameChars